# PostgreSQL - Find in the JSONB array of lat/lng one lat/lng in the radius

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, geo

I have a table `trips` she has a column `points` -> `jsonb` It is the representation of all the points (lat,lng) to be covered in the order for arrival at the destination. I want to list the `trips` in the radius of each of two other points given as parameters.

Something like that:

```bash
                    [p1]                     [p2]
[start]--------------()-----------------------()------------------------[end]
```

- `p1`, `p2` = points (lat,lng)
- `()` = radius in km
- `-----` = trips.points

**trips.points** looks like that

```json
[
    {"lat": -20.87996, "lng": 55.46093}, 
    {"lat": -20.880300000000002, "lng": 55.46019},
    ...
]
```

I've already worked with `earth_distance` but I don't know how to do it from a column in `jsonb`

To try the requests : https://dbfiddle.uk/hMyfGxXD

*Today this column is in `jsonb`, but if it is not the approach best suited to my request, I can consider changing the type with your advice.*

*For example, I can create a new table like below* :

```sql
CREATE TABLE "trip_direction_points" (
  "trip_id" uuid NOT NULL,
  "position" int8 NOT NULL,
  "lat" uuid NOT NULL,
  "lng" uuid NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("trip_id", "position")
);
```

or

```sql
CREATE TABLE "trip_direction_points" (
  "trip_id" uuid NOT NULL,
  "position" int8 NOT NULL,
  "geom" geometry(Point, 4326),
  PRIMARY KEY ("trip_id", "position")
);
```

Comment: In the radius of what?  the radius of each other?  Of a single other point given as a parameter?  Has points in the radius of each of two other points given as parameters?

Comment: @jjanes Has points in the radius of each of two other points given as parameters :D

Comment: This is broken by design. Don't store geometrical data in JSON. Don't store anything you want to use in a geometrical query in an array.

Comment: Thx @LaurenzAlbe Do you have a design suggestion for me to improve my structur ?

Comment: Yes. Use the PostGIS extension and store the points as data type `geometry`, either one point per table row or as a multipoint. That will allow you to write efficient queries and to use GiST indexes.